# Extracting multiple lines from each file in directory, editing text and appending file name for each matching line

Tags: text-processing, sed, python, perl

I have a folder containing multiple files, and from each file I need to 1) extract all lines containing items from a prespecified list of words; 2) pre-pend the file name to that line 3) separate the extracted line into two separate strings, deleting some content in between.

This is the content of the files I need to extract from:

```
freq +fchi +t*CHI +s"m|v"
Fri Feb 24 10:24:17 2017
freq (08-Jan-2016) is conducting analyses on:
  ONLY speaker main tiers matching: *CHI;
    and those speakers' ONLY dependent tiers matching: %MOR;
****************************************
From file <sarah004.cha>
Speaker: *CHI:
  2 v|eye-3S
  1 v|get
  2 v|get&PAST
  1 v|go&PAST
  1 v|help
  2 v|ride
  3 v|see
  1 v|toe-3S
------------------------------
    8  Total number of different item types used
   13  Total number of items (tokens)
0.615  Type/Token ratio
```

An example of the list of words I'm looking for is see|know|look (actual list is much longer, about 25 words).

What I want to end up with is this:

```
sarah004.cha    3    see
sarah006.cha    3    know
sarah010.cha    1    look
sarah010.cha    2    see
...
```

So in addition to extracting lines containing the specified words, I'd also be separating the number and the word and deleting the v|.

Some files in the directory may not contain any of the words on the list, others may contain many of the words on the list.

I'm not sure if I can accomplish this with sed; I tried this as a starting point (just extracting any lines with counts) and it wouldn't finish running:

```
sed '/From file/{s/.*<\(.*\)>/\1/;h
}
/^  [0-9] v|/!d
s/.*= //;H;x' ./* | paste - - > sarahverbcounts.txt
```

I would be fine doing this in multiple steps, although I'm sure it could be accomplished with one command/script and I just don't know how. I think perl could handle this, but I don't know the syntax (I tried using a perl example I found and couldn't figure out how to properly change it for my purposes). Maybe I need try this in Python, which would allow me to specify the word list, but I am not familiar with how to direct Python to iterate over all files in a directory one by one and have them all write to the same output file (I've looked at examples but I don't quite understand them). Any advice is appreciated (and, if possible, explanations of how your solution works would be wonderful, because I'm new enough to this that I can't always parse the helpful answers that I'm given).

Comment: It *looks* like you want something like `awk 'NR==FNR {a["v|"$0]=$0; next} $2 in a {print FILENAME, $1, a[$2]}' wordlist *.cha` (where `wordlist` is a file containing the search words, one per line) - but I'm not sure based on your description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the list of words to search for in a file called `words.txt` and then run:

```
grep -Hf words.txt files.* | sed 's/:/ /;s/v|/ /'
```

Comment: This worked! It uses the names of the files that the strings are extracted from, which has a different extension than the .cha file name contained in the file itself, but that's easily replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways as shown. The patterns are stored, 1 per line in a list file.

Note: We distinguish the patterns file from the remaining data files (presumably your `*cha` files) by different stratagems in bash, perl, & sed.
In case of "sed" the patterns are stored in a dot file, aka hidden files, &
appended with a "." to assist "sed" code in distinguishing a pattern file
from a regular data file. This is a WA for sed as it does not have as in
awk the concept of "FNR".

## Grep

```
grep -E -f ./.your_patterns_listfile ./* |
sed -e 's/://' -e 's/v|//'
```

## Perl

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -exec \
   perl -wMstrict -Mvars='*pat' -lne '
      BEGIN { ($pat) = @ARGV; }
      if ( $pat ne $ARGV ) {
         @pat = map { quotemeta } keys %pat unless @pat;
         next unless /^From file [<]/ .. /^--*/;
         my $cha;
         /^From file [<]([>]*)[>]/ and $cha = $1;
         for my $pat ( @pat ) {
            /^\s+ (\d+) \s+ v[|] ($pat) $/x and print(join("\t",$ARGV,$1,$2)),last
         }
      } else {
         $pat{$_}++;
      }
   ' ./your_patterns_listfile {} +
```

## Sed

```
echo '.' >> ./.your_patterns_listfile
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*' -exec \
   sed -e '
      1{
         :pats
            N
         /\n\.$/!bpats
         s///;h;d
      }

      /^From file </!d
      $d;N
      /\n[ ]*\([1-9][0-9]*\)[ ]v|/{
         s//\n\1\t|/;s/$/|/
         G;s/\n/&&/;s/$/\n/
         /\n\n[1-9][0-9]*\t|\([^|]*\)|.*\n\1\n/{
            s/^From file <\([^>]*\)>\n\n\([1-9][0-9]*\)\t|\([^|]*\)|/\1\t\2\t\3\n&/
            P;s/\n\n.*//;D
         }
      }
      s/\n.*//;s/^/\n/;D
   ' ./.your_patterns_listfile {} +
```

## Bash

```
find . -type f -name '*' ! -name 'your_patterns_listfile' -exec \
   sh -c '
      shift $1
      flag=
      eval "`echo '\''readonly NL=qsq'\'' | tr '\''qs'\'' '\''\047\012'\''`"; # newline
      pats=$(< $1); shift
      cat "$@" |
      while IFS= read -r line
      do
         case $line in
            "From file <"* )
               cha=${line#*"<"}
               cha=${cha%">"}
               unset flag
               continue
               ;;

            *[0-9]*v\|* )
               pat=${line#*"|"}
               num=${line%%"v"*}
               num=${num//[ ]/}
               case $pats in
                  "$pat" | *"$NL$pat$NL"* | "$pat$NL"* | *"$NL$pat" )
                     ${flag+":"} printf "%s\t" "$cha" "$num" "$pat"
                     ${flag+":"} echo
                     ;;
               esac
               ;;

            '' | *[!-]* )
               :
               ;;

            * )
               flag=
               ;;
         esac
      done
   ' 2 1 ./your_patterns_listfile {} +
```

Comment: Thank you for all of these options and your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
egrep '^\s+[0-9]+\s+v\|([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$' files* | sed -e 's/v|//g'
```

Comment: Where's the prespecified list of words?